# How to pass data between child and parent in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
module.exports= class APP extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      key1:'key1',
      key2:'key2'
    };
  render() {
    return (
       <View>
          <Button
             onPress={this.goToTisch}>
             1
          </Button>
          <Button
             onPress={this.goToTisch}>
             2
          </Button>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I just write an app with react-native and do not know how to update the parent state from  the child element. thank you in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To call Parent's method from child, you can pass the reference like this.

**Parent Class**

```
<ChildClass
    onRef={ref => (this.parentReference = ref)}
    parentReference = {this.parentMethod.bind(this)}
/>

parentMethod(data) {

}
```

**Child Class**

```
let data = {
    id: 'xyz',
    name: 'zzz',
};
```

//This will call the method of parent

```
this.props.parentReference(data);
```

Answer (score 24):

You need to pass from parent to child callback function, and then call it in the child.

For example:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }
  updateState = () => {
      this.setState({
          show: !this.state.show
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Child updateState={this.updateState} />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
      this.props.updateState();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Test</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked it.

Comment: I get a bunch of "Cannot update during en existing state transition" when doing this

Answer (score 4):

Like you do with [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).

You have to [exchange information through props](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props), or use a library like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/).

Answer (score 4):

Using Props like this:

Parent:

```
<Parent>
  <Child onChange={this.change} />
</Parent>
```

Child:

```
<button onclick={this.props.onChange('It Changed')} />
```

With this you can just do whatever you want in your parent.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be achieved by two ways:**

Parent Component:

```
//Needs argument
const addGoalHandler = goalTitle => {
        // code for updating state
}

<GoalInput onAddGoal={this.addGoalHandler} />
```

Child Component:

Way 1: Using Vanilla Javascript

```
<Button 
    title="ADD"
    onPress={props.onAddGoal.bind(this, enteredGoal)}
/>
```

Way 2: Using Arrow Function

```
<Button 
    title="ADD"
    onPress={() => { props.onAddGoal(enteredGoal) } }
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Parent extends Component{
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
    this.state={value:''};
    this.getData=this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  getData(val){
   console.log(val);
  this.setState({
    value:val
  });
  }
    render(){
      const {value}=this.state
    return(
      <View>
      <Screen sendData={this.getData}/>
      <View>
        <Text>
    {this.state.value};
    </Text>
      </View>
      </View>
    )
    }
}
export default Parent;


CHILD CLASS:

class Child extends Component{
   componentWillMount(){
    this.props.sendData('data');
   }
    render(){ 
    return(
        <View>  
       </View>
    )
    }  
}
export default Child;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.