# React Redux update state from dumb child

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there any way to update parent state from dumb child component? I have grid layout which has children (headers and body) and i want fo use headers as filters with input. I connect my grid to db with parent component a pass all my data down to body and headers, but i want to get filters from headers to connected smart component. Only way i found is to connect GridHeader to store and pass data directly to it.

Problem with my solutoin is that i want to use my grid in diferent pages with diferent data types so i need all my grid components to be dumb. With my solution i have to write specific GridHeader for every data/table type and connect every header to different store key. One would be connected to `catalog: store.catalog` second would be `users: store.users` etc...
My solution its not DRY and i dont like it :/ Please help

Here is my GridHeader:

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { filterCatalog, setFilters } from '../../redux/actions/catalogActions';

@connect((store) => {
    return {
        catalog: store.catalog
    };
})
export default class GridHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const name = e.target.name;
        let filters = {
            [name]: e.target.value
        }
        this.props.dispatch(setFilters(filters))
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        if (e.which == 13){
            e.target.blur();
            //console.log('submit', this.props.catalog.filters)
            this.props.dispatch(filterCatalog(this.props.catalog.filters))
        }
    }

    render() {
        const headerItem = this.props.headers.map((x) => {
            return (
                <th class={x.class} key={x.name}>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type={x.type} id={x.id} name={x.name} placeholder={x.placeholder} class={x.class} disabled={x.disabled} onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyPress={this.handleSubmit}/>
                    <label for={x.name}>{x.label}</label>
                </div>
                <a class="filter-button hidden">
                    <i class="material-icons">backspace</i>
                </a>
            </th>
            )
        });

        return (
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {headerItem}
                </tr>
            </thead>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: not entirely sure what your question is. sounds like you should just name your variables more generically? `store => ({ item: store.catalog })` and `updateItem` as actions?

Comment: also, just to answer your general question, there's no such thing as a "dumb" component. it's just a term to describe a component that's more generic, so yes of course you can call functions from any component, and those functions can trigger dispatch calls

Comment: This is good sulition, but consider example where I have two grids on one page, then both will connect to same store object which is bad :/

Answer (score 0):

You could create wrapper component which will be provide data for GridHeader. For example:

First usage

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
      catalog: store.catalog
  };
})
export default class FirstWrapperGridHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <GridHeader {...props} />
  }
}
```

Second usage:

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
      catalog: store.anotherData
  };
})
export default class SecondWrapperGridHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <GridHeader {...props} />
  }
}
```

Your GridHeader should be not connected to redux store,should be just dumb.

Comment: But I wanted to get data from GridHeader to its parent (or grandparent in my case), your solution gives data from store to GridHeader

Comment: So need to also add react state to your parent and pass to child component callback function which will be change your state. check my another anser here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638032/how-to-pass-data-between-child-and-parent-in-react-native/41638190#41638190

Comment: But with redux all states should be handled by redux. Or at least I read that somewhere