# How to send data from next screen to previous screen and append data in an array in previous screen state variable in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a situation where I want to send data from **second screen** to **first screen** class. Every time when I redirect from **first screen** to **second screen** and comeback from **second screen** to **first screen**, I want to pass data to Parent and append in an array in **first screen** class.

first screen :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.navigation.getParam('sizeData') != undefined) {
      if (this.props.navigation.getParam('sizeData') != this.state.sizeData) {
            let sizeDataArray = this.props.navigation.getParam('sizeData');
              this.setState({
                sizeData: [...this.state.sizeData, sizeDataArray],
              )}
      }
    }
 }
```

second screen:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AddArticle', {
      sizeData: this.state.sizeData,
    });
```

In this situation when I try to append data, then componentDidUpdate creates an infinite loop. Can anyone provide some other method?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: HI, and welcome to Stackoverflow - please try to include information about what you've tried, including any code. That let us more understand how to help you.  [how-to-ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between child and parent in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638032/how-to-pass-data-between-child-and-parent-in-react-native)

Comment: Regarding your infinite loop, this is not the intended use of [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). If you're following the guideline that you should check the state before calling `setState`, your second if should be something like `if (this.props.navigation.getParam('sizeData') != this.state.sizeData[this.state.sizeData.length - 1])`

Comment: @artcorpse I already checked how to pass data from child to parent but while implementing if I call <ChildClass> in parent class, it renders the ChildClass UI in parent class which is not required by me right now. Thanx btw :)

Comment: The parent/child relationship in react-native is usually that where a component the "parent" contains another component the "child". It might make sense to rephrase your question to explain your navigation set-up, if this is not what you mean by "parent" and "child"

Comment: @artcorpse edited now, please check and answer. I am noob to react native

Answer (score 0):

You get an infinite loop, because you don't correctly detect the screen change, and then updates are triggered again and again by your implementation of [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

The documentation of react-navigation suggests that you use the following trick to only call your state update once ([link here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/function-after-focusing-screen/#example)):

```js
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
            let sizeDataParam = this.props.navigation.getParam('sizeData');
            if (sizeDataParam != undefined) {
                this.setState({
                    sizeData: [...this.state.sizeData, sizeDataParam],
                )}
            }
        }
    }
```